# Почему при запуске рассылки выдается проблема: Chat not found?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, бот, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['sendall'])
async def sendall(message: types.Message):
   if message.chat.type == 'private':
        text = message.text[9:]
        users = db.get_users()
        for row in users:
            try:
                await bot.send_message(row[0], text )
                if int(row[1]) !=1:
                    db.set_active(row[0], 1)    
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                db.set_active(row[0], 0)

        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"Успешная рассылка")
```

Не понимаю почему такая ошибка, боту ранее отправлялись сообщения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Дайте все сообщение об ошибке